# Gitlab-ci - Display warning on merge if a given file has been modified

Tags: gitlab-ci

I wish to know if it's possible to display a message when merging a branch with gitlab if a given file has been modified.

To be clearer, if the configuration file has been modified, I might need to update the configuration file on others environment, which is easy to forget. That's why I would like to display "Have you updated configuration everywhere ?" (or something to that effect) every time I merge a branch where the configuration has been modified.

I did some digging, it seems possible to list modified file but so far I have no idea how to display a warning.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

There is no particular way to raise a custom user-defined warning/message in the MR UI. However, there may be some solutions that might work for you.

### Using codeowners

You can use [CODEOWNERS](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/code_owners.html) and an [approval rule](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/approvals/) that requires approval for codeowners when owned files are modified. That way, every time the file(s) you define are modified, there will be an approval rule that appears in the MR UI. However, it won't include any kind of user-defined message.

### Custom approval rule

Another way may be to define a custom approval rule called something descriptive like "did you update the config?" -- however, this would not be conditional based upon whether the file was modified or not; it would show up on every MR.

[image: approval UI]

### A custom pipeline job

You could use a custom pipeline job to determine whether a check is needed. This pipeline job, in principle, could make a comment on your MR when it detects the file has changed. Or maybe even analyze if a config file change is needed and fail the pipeline.

### A custom service/webhook

For a similar use-case to what you describe, I created an approval rule and a MR webhook for MR events that would, depending on the contents of the MR, automatically provide approval from a bot user whenever human approval was determined to be not required. Though, this requires creating a service to respond to the webhooks.

In other words: if no action was needed, the bot approved the MR for you (satisfying the custom approval rule). If action was required, the bot would do nothing, meaning a human would have to approve to satisfy the approval rule.

Something like a similar comment from a bot user may also work for your use case.

### other ways of surfacing information in MRs

Some other features of GitLab cause messages to appear in the UI, so you could (ab)use those features to surface custom-ish messages, like:

1. [Metrics reports](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/metrics_reports.html) in MRs
2. [SAST scanning](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/application_security/sast/#customize-rulesets) results in MRs
3. Maybe some others?